# How to reliably find app InstallLocation without WMI

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry, windows-installer

I'm trying to find if an app is installed, and what the installed path is.  I have tried using WMI `Win32_SoftwareElement` and also enumerating the following registry keys

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
- `HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

What I've found out is that although it's the fastest method (as opposed to WMI) it's not as reliable.  Not all apps are listed, and out of those listed, not all have their `InstallLocation` properly set.  Searching `Win32_SoftwareElement` yielded the best result, but it is sluggish, wondering if there is any better alternative, perhaps a reg location I failed to include in my search, or if there are other alternatives to WMI, like P/Invoke.

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74311529/5514131

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The install location isn't always set because it's not automatic. Some installs might not be MSI-based installs and I don't know if the other tools that are used will all set the location. If it's an MSI-based install the location is there only if the package developer sets the ARPINSTALLOCATION property during the install to the actual location.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367589(v=vs.85).aspx

The plain old Win32 Windows Installer API to enumerate installed products is MsiEnumProducts () to return the ProductCode values one at a time, then to call MsiGetProductInfo() passing that product code guid and asking for INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLLOCATION, but again that's only there if the MSI developer did the right thing.

There's no reliable way to get installed products all at once because some are MSI-based, some are not, and they may or may not set the install location, and that install location is typically only the application directory and doesn't include files installed in any number of other places so it's value is minimal. Trawling through the registry and making decisions on what you find seems to be the only way to get the list.

Having said all that, short answer is that if you know a ProductCode then call MsiGetProductInfo() as above and get the location!

Comment: Yes I have come to find out that this is not always set.  The thing that puzzles me is how is **Win32_SoftwareElement** able to retrieve apps that are not even listed in those directory keys, and get the InstallLocation?  This app I'm having the problem with happens to be listed in add/remove programs, though doesn't seem to have an install location there either  :(

Comment: @PhilDW Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74311529/5514131

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's no clear answer on StackOverflow how to do this, even though it's possible to do it somewhat reliably in case you know that installer is using `MSI`. I'll use C++, but it's simple to port it to C#:

- First, we must obtain the `ProductId`. You either know it already, use `gwmi win32_product -filter "Name like '%<product_name_pattern>%'" -namespace root/cimv2`, or some other way to obtain it (e.g. with `MsiEnumProductsW` and `MsiGetProductInfoW` or by using upgrade_code and `MsiEnumRelatedProductsW`)
- we try getting the `InstallLocation` directly:

```cpp
  DWORD buf_size = MAX_PATH;
  wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH];
  if(ERROR_SUCCESS != MsiGetProductInfoW(Product_ID, INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLLOCATION, buf, &buf_size) || !buf_size)
  {
    return buf;
  }
```

As you already know, that won't work for some installers, because setting [ARPINSTALLLOCATION property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/win32/msi/arpinstalllocation?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is optional (interesting design choice). However, Windows still correctly uninstalls those, so it must know something that we don't. MSI uses simple relational DB to organize its stuff, and [Orca](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/orca-exe) allows us to browse it. For example, here's node.js installer:

[image]
`Component` column is just a name node authors used/generated via some installer toolset, `KeyPath` is a file name (or registry key etc.) which this component installs, and finally `ComponentId` is a GUID and used by Windows to uniquely identify files to uninstall.

Since we have the `ProductId`, we can find path of the cached .msi installer and query its DB to get all ComponentIds and their actual paths using `MsiGetComponentPathW`:

```cpp
using unique_msi_handle = wil::unique_any<MSIHANDLE, decltype(&::MsiCloseHandle), ::MsiCloseHandle>;

if(ERROR_SUCCESS != MsiGetProductInfoW(Product_ID, INSTALLPROPERTY_LOCALPACKAGE, nullptr, &package_path_size))
{
  return;
}
std::wstring package_path(++package_path_size, L'\0');

if(ERROR_SUCCESS != MsiGetProductInfoW(Product_ID, INSTALLPROPERTY_LOCALPACKAGE, package_path.data(), &package_path_size))
{
  return;
}
package_path.resize(size(package_path) - 1); // trim additional \0 which we got from MsiGetProductInfoW

unique_msi_handle db_handle;
if(ERROR_SUCCESS != MsiOpenDatabaseW(package_path.data(), (wchar_t *)MSIDBOPEN_READONLY, &db_handle))
{
  return;
}

unique_msi_handle view;
if(ERROR_SUCCESS != MsiDatabaseOpenViewW(db_handle.get(), L"select ComponentId from Component", &view))
{
  return;
}

if(ERROR_SUCCESS != MsiViewExecute(view.get(), 0))
{
  return;
}

unique_msi_handle record;
while(ERROR_SUCCESS == MsiViewFetch(view.get(), &record))
{
  wchar_t component_id[guid_length];
  DWORD component_id_len = guid_length;
  MsiRecordGetStringW(record.get(), 1, component_id, &component_id_len);
  wchar_t path[256];
  DWORD path_size = 256;
  MsiGetComponentPathW(Product_ID, component_id, path, &path_size);

  std::wcout << component_id << L": " << path << '\n';
}
```

As @PhilDW mentioned, this probably crawls registry under the hood. Output for node.js:

```
{BE71D092-38E4-5DED-B176-D60079E51615}: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
{1A357DF6-3AF1-5A76-AE55-3676CCFA4513}: 22:\SOFTWARE\Node.js\InstallPath
{26837A22-55BA-5207-B2DE-0F7366E8FB8E}: C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat
{EE1FC8BD-57FF-514B-8950-359974C2C6B9}: C:\Program Files\nodejs\install_tools.bat
{8B344AC8-9B54-5327-9D16-CE528884AC7E}: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_etw_provider.man
{A194E0CC-E739-5C8B-947E-BD9463D8341A}: 21:\SOFTWARE\Node.js\Components\NodeStartMenuShortcuts
{B466EFC0-4255-51C5-8E26-3D8258F1AB57}: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
{CA3A5DB4-0430-533D-83BC-7044D32BAE9E}: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
{1BDBC761-41B0-51F4-8D42-42AD24077B91}: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npx.cmd
{F4384E08-1315-5F41-B086-F78BD6C0EE84}: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npx
{781AE8C4-C809-5E2B-A2C8-132EE6210483}: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc
...
```

As you can see, there's a lot of options to go from here:

- Inferring the installation path using the all components (if you don't know anything about the software you uninstalling).
- If you know some file which is placed in the installation root, e.g. `node.exe`, just find take its prefix.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I was able to port it to .NET, check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74311529/5514131

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the Accepted answer, where the target program does not use the `InstallLocation` property to tell us where it was installed. You can get the program install location by enumerating the program installed components, the solution will also include program files installed in other locations. The solution is very fast compared to WMI.

1. Assuming we have the target program code, use the `MsiGetProductInfo` Windows Installer API to get the program cached package path `INSTALLPROPERTY_LOCALPACKAGE` .

   ```
    <DllImport("msi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Private Function MsiGetProductInfo(ByVal product As String, ByVal [property] As String, <Out> ByVal valueBuf As StringBuilder, ByRef len As Int32) As Int32
    End Function

    Dim len = 512
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder(len)
    MsiGetProductInfo("{643C3762-7237-49F5-AD5E-5309C1B8EBCD}", "LocalPackage", sb, len)

    Dim msiPath = sb.ToString
   ```
2. Parse the program Windows Installer database by installing this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DTF-Unofficial/ which is a wrapper of Windows Installer APIs.
3. Query the program `component` table to enumerate the program component Ids.

   ```
    Dim lstComponents As New List(Of String)

    Using database = New Database(msiPath, DatabaseOpenMode.[ReadOnly])

        Using view = database.OpenView(database.Tables("Component").SqlSelectString)

            view.Execute()

            For Each rec In view

                Using rec
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", rec.GetString("ComponentId"), rec.GetString("Component"))
                    lstComponents.Add(rec.GetString("ComponentId"))
                End Using

            Next

        End Using

    End Using
   ```
4. Get each program component file path/Registry location using the `MsiGetComponentPath` API

   ```
    <DllImport("msi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Public Function MsiGetComponentPath(ByVal szProduct As String, ByVal szComponent As String, <Out> ByVal lpPathBuf As StringBuilder, ByRef pcchBuf As UInt32) As UInt32
    End Function

    For Each comId In lstComponents

        Dim sbPath As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(500)

        Dim chs As UInteger = 500
        MsiGetComponentPath("{643C3762-7237-49F5-AD5E-5309C1B8EBCD}", comId, sbPath, chs)

        Console.WriteLine(sbPath.ToString)

    Next
   ```

References:

[MsiGetProductInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msi/nf-msi-msigetproductinfoa)

[MsiGetComponentPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msi/nf-msi-msigetcomponentpatha)